# In a selenium webdriver script for user registration , how to handle unique email id is given in the script?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have created basic selenium web driver script for user registration. there are 4 fields for user registration email id, first name , last name and phone number.Email id field has duplication checking . So if i execute script again , the test will fail because of duplicate email id validation. How to handle this situation ??? each time we have to modify the email id manually in script ??

Comment: Why would you do it manually? Just create a random email...

Answer (score 0):

You may try to generate a random email id each time and check if it is a duplicate after submission. If your generated email is duplicate, iterate the process with a newly generated email id. Pseudocode:

```
String email = generateEmailId(); // generate a random email id

/*
  put your code here for filling up form
  and submit the form
 After submitting the form check if the duplicate email id validation message appears. If it happen then re-submit your form with a newly generated email
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I get around this by appending a number to the email user portion based on UTC (in milliseconds). For example in python:

```
from time import time

"random_{}".format(int(time() * 1E6))
```